# Countif for counting data for a month

Tags: countif

I have a data and have applied Count if formula to get the number, but need to filter more for a month which is not working for me. Now i have dates in Column F, and need to include it for the month of January for the below applied formula.

```
=COUNTIFS('Joiners Base Data'!C:C,A2,'Joiners Base Data'!O:O,C2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.
    =COUNTIFS('Joiners Base Data'!C:C,A8,'Joiners Base Data'!O:O,"IT",'Joiners Base Data'!AQ:AQ,">="&DATE(2017,3,1),'Joiners Base Data'!AQ:AQ,"<"&DATE(2017,4,1))